# Can I estimate Wi-Fi's power transmission in function of the amount of data transmitted?

Tags: power, wifi, transmitter

For a specific device connected to specific AP. Can I estimate the differences in radiation power (mWh) depending on the data transmitted (2KB/s vs 200KB/s)?

If so, how?

Comment: Have you read the Wifi spec to determine if there is a relationship? Have you made any measurements?

Comment: Power would be mW not mWh. mWh could be energy.

Comment: Transmission power it is not related with bandwidth, but it is related with the receiver sensitivity and modulation schemes (dBm at x Mbps in DFM, QPSK, CCK, OFDM…) at a range of –68dBm to –94dBm.
Then you can calculate propagation losses, Tx antenna gain, Transmitter power…

Answer (score 1):

If two radio systems are operating at broadly the same frequency, using the same type of antennas and over the same distance and terrain, a theoretical comparative judgement can be made. The judgement is based on the assumption that a receiver (at a lower data rate) requires less received power at its antenna compared to the receiver operating at the higher data rate.

The required power for a receiver is -154dBm + 10log\$_{10}\$ (bit rate)

Ignoring the -154dBm (because we are making comparisons) it can be seen that: -

10log\$_{10}\$ (200,000) = 53 dBm and

10log\$_{10}\$ (2,000) = 33 dBm

I've ignored "B" (bytes) and assumed "b" (bits) in the equation but it makes no difference; 2 kbps requires a power level at the antenna that is 20 dB smaller than 200 kbps for the same bit error rate.

In real money, that means one-hundredth of the power is required to be transmitted for 2kbps, all other things being equal.